# Changing line type / width for each time series with autoplot and ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

I am trying to create one plot to include two time-series:

```
library(zoo)
library(tseries)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggfortify)

ts1 <- ts(c(1,2,3,4))
ts2 <- ts(c(1.1, 2.1, 3.1, 4.1))
autoplot(ts.union(ts1, ts2), facets = FALSE) +
scale_color_manual(breaks = c("ts1", "ts2"), labels = c("Actual", "Forecasted"), values=c("black", "red"))
```

After changing the legend titles and colors for each series I want to modify the line width and type, also by series, but calling `scale_linetype_manual` does not seem to change the plot by a bit. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the respective aesthetics to your plot before you can change them. For this you need to know the name of the variable that `autoplot` uses for aesthetic mapping: see the name of the colour scale.

The data frame that is used for plotting looks like this

```
#  Index plot_group value
#1     1        ts1   1.0
#2     2        ts1   2.0
#3     3        ts1   3.0
#4     4        ts1   4.0
#5     1        ts2   1.1
#6     2        ts2   2.1
#7     3        ts2   3.1
#8     4        ts2   4.1
```

`autoplot` creates the column `plot_group` for you and in order to distinguish the two time series, it maps (only) the colour to it. Hence you could call `scale_color_manual`.

You can use this variable to map another aesthetics to it, for example `size` and `linetype`.

```
autoplot(ts.union(ts1, ts2), facets = FALSE) +
 scale_color_manual(labels = c("Actual", "Forecasted"),
                    values=c("black", "red")) +
 aes(linetype = plot_group,
     size = plot_group) +
 scale_linetype_manual(labels = c("Actual", "Forecasted"),
                       values = c(1, 2)) +
 scale_size_manual(labels = c("Actual", "Forecasted"),
                   values = c(1, 2))
```

[image]

**data**

```
p <- autoplot(ts.union(ts1, ts2), facets = FALSE)
p$data
```

Comment: Just a minor follow-up question - does the labels command have to supply labels according to an alphabetical order of values in the plot_group column? Say I have "banana" and "apple" as values in the plot_group column, and I want to label them as "ts1" and "ts2", should I supply these as labels = c("ts2", "ts1") such that it matches them in alphebetical order?

Comment: see `?scale_colour_manual`for details. If the vector you pass to labels is unnamed, the arguments will be matches alphabetically. Try `+ scale_color_manual(labels = c(ts2 = "Actual", ts1 = "Forecasted"))` to see what happens. You will always be on the save side if you name these vectors, i.e. `values`, `labels` etc.

Comment: By the way, there is no need for the `zoo` and `tseries` packages, I guess. Also the `breaks` argument in `scale_colour_manual` is not necessary.