# Time Series Plot using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, trendline, ggfortify

How can I make changes to the following things in this graph?

1. Change the colour of trend line (currently blue)
2. Change the colour of the peak points (currently orange)
3. Change the colour of the Time series Pattern Line(currently black)
4. Add a legend to indicate the colour of all the three above

[Here's the Plot I got from the code source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFUp8.jpg)

[image]

Code Source:

```
# Libraries used: 
library(ggplot2)
library(timeSeries)
library(ggfortify)
library(ggthemes)
library(dplyr)
library(strucchange)

strucchange::breakpoints(AirPassengers ~ 1) %>%
  autoplot(ts.linetype = 'solid', ts.size = 1.1, ts.geom = 'line')+
  geom_smooth(aes(y=AirPassengers), 
              method = "loess", se= F,
              lwd = 1.2) +
  geom_point(aes(y = AirPassengers), size = 1.5, shape = 16, color = "orange3")+
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 years", date_labels = "%Y")+
  labs(title = "Yearly Time Series", 
       subtitle="Sales trend from Year 2001 to 2017", 
       caption="Source: Airpassengers Time Series Analysis", 
       y="Sales", x = "Years")+
  theme_economist_white()+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = -.1))
```

Comment: Check these links: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggfortify/vignettes/plot_ts.html & https://stackoverflow.com/a/48431977/786542

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first three changes can be made using the following syntax:

```
strucchange::breakpoints(AirPassengers ~ 1) %>%
  autoplot(ts.linetype = 'solid', ts.size = 1.1, ts.geom = 'line', fill = "red")+
  geom_smooth(aes(y=AirPassengers), 
          method = "loess", se= F,
          lwd = 1.2, color = "green") +
  geom_point(aes(y = AirPassengers), size = 1.5, shape = 16, color = "blue")+
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 years", date_labels = "%Y")+
  labs(title = "Yearly Time Series", 
   subtitle="Sales trend from Year 2001 to 2017", 
   caption="Source: Airpassengers Time Series Analysis", 
   y="Sales", x = "Years")+
 theme_economist_white()+
 theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = -.1))
```

[image]

The color of the trend line is changed by specifying `color = "green"` in the call to `geom_smooth`. The same is done for the peak points in `geom_point`. Lastly, `autoplot` in this case doesn't seem to know `color`, but it works with specifying `fill = "red"` (this throws a warning, but works nonetheless).

I am not clear how you want your legend to look, can you clarify in the comments?

Comment: You can use `ts.colour` & `ts.fill` for `autoplot`. Type `help(autoplot.ts)` to see details

Comment: Yes, but the result is the same. `ts.color` doesn't change anything. `ts.fill` does but throws a warning

Comment: The legend is just an indicator of the colour of lines like red -> TS-line, green  -> trend line, blue-> peak points &  position of the legend can be at the "top right"  to clearly convey what the lines mean in the graph [link] *(http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Legends_(ggplot2)/)* like in this website. Although the legends here are for groups I want them to indicate the lines and what they stand for

Comment: I am sorry, I don't know anything about `ts.autoplot()`and  can't get to the the `ts.fill` part to get passed to a custom legend. I have only been able to create a legend for the two standard ggplot `geom`s. Here's hoping someone else can help

Comment: It works! adding legend manually using `scale_colour_manual()` and `scale_fill_manual()`. Thanks a bunch! the tip to create '*legend for two standard ggplot's `geom`*' reminded me of it.